# Prove that the level curves of $\log\frac{|z-\sqrt{z^2-1}|}{2}$ are ellipses

Tags: complex-analysis, conic-sections

In a book it was mentioned that the level curves of the complex function $\phi (z) = \log\frac{|z-\sqrt{z^2-1}|}{2}$ is an ellipse with foci $1$ and $-1$. I can not establish a relation between the ellipse equation in the complex plane $|z-a|+|z-b|=c$ and the function $\phi(z)$. Is the change of variable possible here? (for example I tried $z = \sinh\omega$ but it did not work).

Can anyone help me to prove it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by $\phi$ being an ellipse? Like an image of a set under $\phi$ is an ellipse?

Comment: @Ennar I mean the level curves of $\phi(z)$ are ellipse. I'll edit it now.

Comment: You may need to change the title. $\log\cdots$ is just a real number but not an ellipse.

Comment: For example, we may phrase it as "Prove that for each $l$, $\{z\in\mathbb{C} \mid \log\cdots = l\}$ is an ellipse.

Comment: Try $z=\cosh\omega$, then things simplify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just ignore $\log$ and $2$ in the fraction, and concentrate on $|z-\sqrt{z^2-1}| = r$ for $r>0$.

Let $w = z-\sqrt{z^2-1}$. Then $z - w = \sqrt{z^2-1}$  and $(z-w)^2 = z^2 - 1$. It follows that $z = \frac{w^2+1}{2w}.$ We have

\begin{align}
\left| \frac{w^2+1}{2w} + 1 \right| + \left| \frac{w^2+1}{2w} - 1 \right| &= \left| \frac{(w+1)^2}{2w}\right| + \left| \frac{(w-1)^2}{2w}\right|\\
&= \frac{(w+1)(\overline w + 1)}{2|w|} + \frac{(w-1)(\overline w - 1)}{2|w|}\\
&= \frac{w\overline w + w + \overline w + 1}{2|w|} + \frac{w\overline w - w - \overline w + 1}{2|w|}\\
&= \frac{|w|^2 + 1}{|w|}
\end{align}

and thus if $|w|$ is constant, so is $\left| \frac{w^2+1}{2w} + 1 \right| + \left| \frac{w^2+1}{2w} - 1 \right|$. Therefore, solutions of $|z-\sqrt{z^2-1}|=r$ lie on an ellipse.

However, it seems [the contours are actually not the whole ellipses](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot3D%5BLog%5BAbs%5Bx+%2B+I+y+-+Sqrt%5B(x+%2B+I+y)%5E2+-+1%5D%5D%5D%2F2,+%7Bx,+-3,+3%7D,+%7By,+-3,+3%7D%5D).

Comment: @ccorn, you are right, thank you :)

Comment: The winding number calculation seems to require $r<1$ (so that the argument of the $\ln$ does not need to cross a branch cut). Of course $f(w)=f(1/w)$ and $r=1$ is special anyway, so that is not much hindrance.

Comment: @ccorn, actually, there is a mistake already in the assumption that $z = \frac{w^2+1}{2w}$ is a solution for any $w$. It depends on the argument of $\frac{w^2-1}{2w}$ because not always will $\sqrt{u^2}$ simplify to $u$. But, it seems that the problem is ill posed anyway, [contours are actually half of an ellipse](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot3D%5BLog%5BAbs%5Bx+%2B+I+y+-+Sqrt%5B(x+%2B+I+y)%5E2+-+1%5D%5D%5D%2F2,+%7Bx,+-3,+3%7D,+%7By,+-3,+3%7D%5D).

Comment: @Ennar thanks that was nice. The book I found this was "a practical guide to pseudospectral methods" about using Chebyshev points instead of equispaced points in polynomial interpolation in $[-1,1]$ (the potential  of the interpolant). The issue you posed is correct and the contours are half-ellipses for the level curves of $\phi$. However, this problem won't happen for the interpolant of the points (both equispaced and Chebyshev points) and the contours are complete ellipses. I will add a MATLAB code in the next comment about these contours.

Comment: N = 10;
x = -1+2*(0:N)/N;
p = poly(x);
[x,y] = meshgrid(-3:0.02:3,-3:0.02:3); z = x+1i*y;
pvalue = polyval(p,z);l = 10.^(-4:5);
contour(xx,yy,abs(pp),l)

Answer (score 2):

You know that $|z - \sqrt{z^2 - 1}| = c$, where c is a real number.  This defines some level curve of $\phi(z)$.  Try substituting $z = x + iy$ and seeing whether this leads to the equation of an ellipse.